# Kendo UI Validation Error message being placed on wrong field

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

AS my question says when I intentionally enter in a string that contains invalid characters, and the problem is that its placing the error message on the incorrect field..

So if you placed 87/9*8-=+ (or something to that effect) in the Zip field (where the Zip placeholder is)

and click the button, you'll see that the error message is on the City field, and not on the Zip field

Anyone know from this example why this is happening? (this is part of a lot more fields)

Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  CreateValidation();
  $("#btn").on("click", (e) => {
    const val = $("#NewCustomer").getKendoValidator();
    if (val) {
      val.validate();
    }
  });
});

function CheckString(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    const re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\[\]\.\\="\-#']*$/;
    return re.test(str);
  }
}

function CreateValidation() {
  const CustomerInputs = $("#NewCustomer").kendoValidator({
    errorTemplate: ({
      message
    }) => `<span style="color:red">${message}</span>`,
    messages: {
      StringCheck: "Contains invalid characters",
      required: ""
    },
    rules: {
      StringCheck: function(input) {
        if (input.is("[check-for=string]")) {
          return CheckString(input.val());
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
  }).getKendoValidator();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.425/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="NewCustomer">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="txtCity" label-name="City" required check-for="string" type="text" class="form-control input-sm max-size" placeholder="City" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="txtZip" required label-name="Zip" type="text" check-for="string" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Zip" />
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the [custom error messages](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/validator/rules#custom-messages) to work properly, you need to set a `name` attribute to the input element.

By doing so you can ckech `if (input.is("[name='Zip']"))` and the error messages will be displayed to the corresponding input - [updated example](https://dojo.telerik.com/IgEbIsEh).

Comment: Ah, thats right. I read the link you provided and i must have glossed over the fact that using the name attribute was required and couldn't use a made up attribute. Thanks!